# Warning on "$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = MSU_REQUEST_URI;"

Tags: php, warnings

the line `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = MSU_REQUEST_URI;
Fills my errorslog with`

> Use of undefined constant MSU_PHPEX_PS - assumed 'MSU_PHPEX_PS' (this
>        will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

So I was thinking to solved it with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'MSU_REQUEST_URI';`
Than is the warning gone but the script isn't working any longer.
Any ideas?

Comment: What is `MSU_REQUEST_URI` ??

Comment: `PHPBB` Forum system uses `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];` as `MSU_REQUEST_URI` as a `defined` you just needed to use `MSU_REQUEST_URI` instead `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'MSU_REQUEST_URI';`

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you're having is that `MSU_REQUEST_URI` is **undefined**

This means whatever value you expected the constant `MSU_REQUEST_URI` to have, has not been set at the time of you executing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = MSU_REQUEST_URI;`,

By surrounding `MSU_REQUEST_URI` with quotes like this `'MSU_REQUEST_URI'` you are assigning the **String Value (literally) "MSU_REQUEST_URI"** to `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

So as @alithedeveloper has asked in the comments:

What is `MSU_REQUEST_URI` supposed to be and how/where is it supposed to get it's value from?

You won't be able to solve your issue without figuring out why `MSU_REQUEST_URI` is not set.

Comment: I found a other page with code about the MSU_REQUEST_URI

Comment: Another page as in another .php file in your project or some random online website which was using that const in it's code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response I found a other page with code about the MSU_REQUEST_URI

```
 <?php
if(defined('MSU_REQUEST_URI')) {
    return;
}

if(version_compare(PHPBB_VERSION, '3.1', '>=')) {
    global $phpEx;
    // Fixing Symphony rewrite compatibility
    $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '';
    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
    define('MSU_REQUEST_URI', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if(
        in_array(
            basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),
            array(
                'viewtopic.'.$phpEx,
                'viewforum.'.$phpEx,
                'search.'.$phpEx,
                'memberlist.'.$phpEx,
                'faq.'.$phpEx,
                'viewonline.'.$phpEx,
                'ucp.'.$phpEx
            )
        )
    ) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].(!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '');
    }
    if(!defined('PHPBB_USE_BOARD_URL_PATH')) {
        define('PHPBB_USE_BOARD_URL_PATH', true);
    }
}

?>
```

Is that helping

Comment: 1. Is this from a file within your project/website or is it from some random website online which you found? 2. Why are you trying to set your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the value of `MSU_REQUEST_URI`? 3. This file actually defines `MSU_REQUEST_URI` if it's not yet set so if you can get this file to execute before your assignment, then your code should start working correctly without the `''` quotes.

Comment: It is a other page in my project, everything is working except the errors that filling my error log

Comment: Ok can you do 2 things please: 1. Answer this question "Why do you want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`  to have the value of `MSU_REQUEST_URI`?
2. Search up all occurrences of `define("MSU_REQUEST_URI",` and `const MSU_REQUEST_URI =` and tell me how many results you get.

Comment: Sorry I think it is to difficult for me.

Comment: Alright if you say so, in that case I'd advise to maybe remove/delete this question, I highly doubt anyone (who doesn't know the specific framework you're using) would be able to help you any further.

If you want to try another go at this question, be sure to inform yourself about the circumstances of your project (What Framework does it use, which PHP version, etc.) and then try asking your question again with all those details supplied in the description, that way you'll have a much higher chance of someone being able to help you find a solution to your issue.